# How to calculate median of an array in FIJI/ImageJ?

Tags: arrays, math, median, imagej, fiji

I want to find the median value of a column in the Results table. I am pulling the column out as an array using :

```
Table.getColumn (Column);
```

So now I just need to know how to find the median value of this array. I know that:

```
Array.getStatistics(array, min, max, mean, stdDev)
```

can return other summary statistics, but it doesn't have median for some reason.

I am struggling to find any sort of median function. Does anyone have any idea?

Cross-posted from [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ImageJ/comments/16czxh7/how_to_calculate_median_of_an_array/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) and [Image.sc Forum](https://forum.image.sc/t/how-to-calculate-median-of-an-array-in-fiji-imagej/86066?u=nbstutzman)

Answer (score 0):

The OP got an answer on image.sc which I am copying below for others searching for an answer to this question.

> You can easily find the median of an array using the existing array
> functions. You can use: `Array.sort(array)` - Sorts array , which must
> contain all numbers or all strings. String sorts are case-insensitive.
> ([Built-in Macro Functions](https://imagej.net/ij/developer/macro/functions.html#Top)) to organise your array. Here is some macro
> code for a function that returns the median value for an array.

```java
array1=newArray(3,5,9,2,7);
array2=newArray(10,3,7,9);

print(median(array1));
print(median(array2));


function median(x){
    x=Array.sort(x);
    if (x.length%2>0.5) {
        m=x[floor(x.length/2)];
    }else{
        m=(x[x.length/2]+x[x.length/2-1])/2;
    };
    return m
}
```